# Merge RDBMS and NoSQL database

Tags: mongodb, relational-database, nosql

Ok, let's say I have a large MySql database with 100+ tables.
Although it runs very well I have two tables that can each exceed 100 million entries per year.
On these two tables I have to perform searches and calculations, not just archive information.

I was thinking of tranfering the logic of these tables to a NoSQL database due to it's good scalability.(MongoDB, CouchDB)

Since the information stored in these tables is used in many queries through the application I was thinking if there is a way to create a merge between the two databases.

Although it would be too beautiful to be able to write a sql query that automatically pulls data from the nosql db maybe there is another approach; like using a stored plsql procedure in MySQL to call a query on the NoSQL database. Or calling a system command from plsql and getting the results.

Just want to mention, I used MySQL as an example, it can be anything, Oracle, Postgres.

Comment: Have you heard of Sqoop (http://sqoop.apache.org/) to transfert data between RDBMS and Hadoop ?

Comment: No, but I will deffinetly look into it.

Comment: I'm not getting you. You want to transfer half data of these too tables from RDMBS to nosql or full. If full, then why you want to redirect query.

Comment: No, not full, half from nosql, half from rdbms.

Comment: On a side note, there is a Dissertation Project proposal in my university on merging RDMS and NoSQL databases. seems prety interesting.

Comment: Developing a hybrid rdbms/nosql solution sounds like a long road of pain. Best to work out a proper migration plan then flip the switch when you're good and ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the buzzword for doing something like this is **Polyglot Persistence** (maybe this helps for further research). Mostly you will have to do the integration of this different datastores by yourself. There are two solutions I am aware of, I haven't tested them though.

The first one is using EclipseLink as an abstraction above the two datastores. The first link i found for that: http://blog.eisele.net/2012/11/polyglot-persistence-eclipselink-with.html

The second one is using PostgreSQL and Foreign data wrappers to kind of nest a nosql database within Postgres: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers